# MS Access - How to generate autonumber with sub-autonumber

Tags: ms-access

I'm new in MS Access. Currently i need to create a serial number, an autonumber pair with a sub-autonumber. Something like M1-1,M1-2,M1-3,... M2-1,M2-2,M2-3,... M3-1,M3-2,... The number must be unique.
I created a table for Main running number for M1,M2,M3,... create an index to make it unique. Then another table for sub-number, 1,2,3,4,... after that a MainNum foreign key (relationship) and another Index to make it unique.
But the problem is second table i cant figure out a way to make it an autonumber/running number, because it may repeat itself.

Currently out of idea, need some help.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend to do not use the serial number as primary/foreign key in tables. Use numeric fields for this: autonumber for primary and number for foreign. It works faster and automatically.

For generating serial number create public function, which can return next value or optionally current one depending on arguments. Current values of first and second part of serial number store in table, lock it when generating new number, it will guarantee unique next number even in multiuser environment. Also you may store all generated numbers in table with composite unique index on both numbers.

Comment: So first table i got a primary autonumber and a number for foreign. then  2nd table how i generate serial number with pubilc function? when you mention "lock it", how exactly lock the number?

Answer (score 0):

Make your PK an autonumber and use that for any relationships. For your serial number use two long integer fields (SN1, SN2). In the before_update event of your form, for new records, call a public function to generate new 'serial numbers'.

```
Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
Dim lngSN1 AS Long
Dim lngSN2 as Long
If Me.NewRecord Then
'if SN1 is not to be incremented, set it here to whatever you want
If GetSerials(SN1, SN2) Then
Me!SN1 = lngSN1
Me!SN2 = lngSN2
Else
Cancel = True
End If
End If
End Sub

Public Function GetSerials(ByRef SN1 as Long, ByRef SN2 as Long) AS Boolean
If SN1 = 0 Then
SN1 = Nz(DMax("SN1","<yourTable>"), 0) + 1
SN2 = 1
Else 
SN2 = DMax("SN2", "<yourtable>","SN1=" & SN1) + 1
End IF
GetSerials = True
End Function
```

Build a query with a calculated field to create your composite 'SerialNumber'.

```
SELECT *, "M" & SN1 & "-" & SN2 as SerialNumber FROM <yourtable>
```

Use that query wherever you want to display the SerialNumber.